# How can I list my `at` jobs by date?

Tags: linux, rhel, sort, at

I am using

> atq

command, but I need to list my at jobs by date. 
How is that possible ?

Answer (score 6):

You can pipe the output of `atq` to `sort` and use the `k` switch (sort via key) and `M` (month-sort) to list your jobs by date. For example, the default output would look like:

```
atq
5   Mon Dec 10 19:00:00 2012 a jason
6   Tue Jan 15 05:00:00 2013 a jason
4   Thu Dec  6 19:00:00 2012 a jason
```

Piping through `sort`:

```
atq | sort -r -k3M -k4
6   Tue Jan 15 05:00:00 2013 a jason
5   Mon Dec 10 19:00:00 2012 a jason
4   Thu Dec  6 19:00:00 2012 a jason
```

Where the third field is sorted by month (`-M`) and the fourth field by day. You could also sort by any of the other fields, like the time, by adding another key.